# I started experimenting with Tkinter on python and for some reason I can't seem to give an attribute to a module which seems to result in an error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


def del_text():
    textbox.delete("1.0")


window = tk.Tk()

window.configure(bg='black')

greeting = tk.Label(
    
    text="python is a pain",
    
    foreground="white",

    background="black"
    )

    
greeting.pack()

root = tk.tkinter()

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300)

textbox = tk.Text(frame)

textbox.insert(window,"test")
textbox.after(10, del_text)


window.mainloop()
```

If I phrased it a bit weird just comment. Also yes i've copied from another guy on stack overflow, it's my first day and I'm messing around. To recreate, just copy and paste this into VScode and look at the error

Comment: Its better if you post all the details yourself first. Please update your post with the full error traceback.

Comment: You shouldn't have both `window` and `root` - `window` is the one you created correctly.

Comment: I remember someone saying that "programming is not a game of guess-and-check, even more it is not a game of making the compiler stop crying." you should watch some tutorials on `tkinter` and basic python if you have difficulties understanding concepts, it won't help you if we just tell you the issue, you will solve it and then probably have another one and then you will ask here again something that you should actually already know because those would be the very basics. For example, do you even understand what a _module_ is? also did you copy the code from question or answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `root = tk.tkinter()` to `root = tk.Tk()` It is unclear what you want to achieve, but do note that you are creating two windows: `window` and `root`.

Also change `textbox.insert(window,"test")` to `textbox.insert(tk.INSERT,"test")`

This should now work, creating the window `window` and displaying the message 'python is a pain' and creating the window `root` and displaying the message 'test'.

Hope I was of help!